# Cakephp ajax call tcpdf not showing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, tcpdf

I have a button that calls a funciont of my controller to show a report.

```
        $('#reporte').click( function () {

        $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        processData: false,
        url: "<?= Router::Url(['controller' => 'cab_facturas', 'action' => 'descargar']); ?>",//teacher//getdata/3
        data:{"id_numero":384}, 
        success: function(validationResponse){
            //window.location.href = '/cake/facturacion/cab_facturas/descargar?id_numero=384';  
        }//success 
        });         
    });
```

and my controller:

```
public function descargar()
{
    $this->layout = 'pdf';
    $this->render();
}

my pdf has the classic: 
$pdf_file_name = 'custom_header_footer.pdf';
echo $pdf->Output($pdf_file_name, 'I');
die();
```

I can see the pdf if I put all the link, or creating a cakephp html link it shows, but I need to do with and ajax call. I think it blocks on the success function.